# svn: working copy '.' locked - DHxlsReaderIOS

Tags: ios, xcode, svn

I am making an app using DHxlsReaderIOS to read .xls files. Everything was working fine. I commited to my local git repository through the xcode commit and I believe I remembered to 'push' as well. Then I made a bunch more changes to my code and I tried to run it on my ipad as well as on the simulator. I got this error:

PhaseScriptExecution "Run Script" /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-eykmkngoxcidwffthbwmmbnzenhp/Build/Intermediates/DHxlsReaderIOS.build/Debug-iphoneos/DHxlsReaderIOS.build/Script-DEB78B6414BC793700845894.sh
    cd /Users/me/Documents/MyAp/DHlibxls-master
    /bin/sh -c /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-eykmkngoxcidwffthbwmmbnzenhp/Build/Intermediates/DHxlsReaderIOS.build/Debug-iphoneos/DHxlsReaderIOS.build/Script-DEB78B6414BC793700845894.sh

svn: Working copy '.' locked
svn: run 'svn cleanup' to remove locks (type 'svn help cleanup' for details)
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1

I have been doing all sorts or research since I didn't even know what svn was (I still only sort understand). I tried to run svn cleanup however I got this message whereever I tried to run it from: svn: '.' is not a working copy directory

After more research I realized their should be some .svn files or folders but I have searched everywhere in my harddrive and could not find anything related. I'm at a loss of what is going on or what my next step should be. I was going to just revert but it appears that my previous commit has disappeared and to revert back to the previous one will cost me alot of time.

If anyone could help me out I would really appreciate it. I'm so lost I would appreciate the 'for dummies' version. Thanks. I'm sorry if this is a stupid or obvious question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I figured this out. I'm obviously a bit of a moron. I did not realize that svn would be a hidden folder. I haven't been using osx for very long and I am much more used to windows and how to show hidden folders (or even recognize that there are hidden folders).

So the answer: 1. From the terminal window: defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles YES

1. relaunch finder
2. Open my finder and navigate to my project. Find where the hidden svn folder is located.
3. From Terminal navigate to the folder where the svn folder is hidden.
4. svn cleanup
5. Build app - Success!!

All of these steps I got from stack overflow questions, so once I realized I was looking for a hidden folder and just searching 'svn' would not show anything it was all as the numerous other questions explained.